# how can I shift edit text field focus consecutively

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to make a lock screen, the lock screen basically has four edit text fields, these fields basically take numerical input, no problem in providing the numerical part.

Now the problem I am having is that, the text fields should take only one numerical value,and the edit text fields should change focus, right after one field is provided with a value, how can  achieve this?

Comment: okay found the answer for changing focus using input1.setNextFocusDownId(input2.getId()); , but how do I enter only one numerical value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For only allowing numerical input (and also showing the "number"-keyboard), use the [`inputType`-attribute](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3ainputType) of the EditText class. To only allow entering one digit into the field, you can use the [`android:maxLength`-attibute](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3amaxLength).

Use a [`TextWatcher`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html) to check if the one digit has been entered into the text field and change the focus to the next field.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following property to enter only numbers

```
<EditText android:inputType="number" ... />
```

or

```
<EditText
    android:inputType="phone"
    android:digits="1234567890"
    ...
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a listener to each EditText for when the text changes (make sure the EditText enforces a max length of 1). The logic of this listener will check that the text is a digit and of length 1, then it'll shift focus. Here's the code:

```
EditText et1 = ...;
EditText et2 = ...;
EditText et3 = ...;
EditText et4 = ...;

et1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
   @Override
   public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
      if( s.length() == 1 && Character.isDigit(s.charAt(0)) ) {
         et2.requestFocus();
      }
   }

   @Override
   public void afterTextChanged(Editable e) { }

   @Override
   public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) { }
});

et2.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
   @Override
   public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
      if( s.length() == 1 && Character.isDigit(s.charAt(0)) ) {
         et3.requestFocus();
      }
   }

   @Override
   public void afterTextChanged(Editable e) { }

   @Override
   public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) { }
});

et3.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
   @Override
   public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
      if( s.length() == 1 && Character.isDigit(s.charAt(0)) ) {
         et4.requestFocus();
      }
   }

   @Override
   public void afterTextChanged(Editable e) { }

   @Override
   public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) { }
});
```